# Azure login screen like Firebase Auth?

Tags: azure, firebase, azure-active-directory

The Firebase authentication library has a feature where a user can be logged in with a call like 'loginWithEmailandPassword(username, password)' where the username and pasword can be passed in.

This allows for custom login screens where we can just pass the username and password into the auth libraries.

In Azure authentication seems to require a separate link to be visisted where we go through the Azure authentication flow after which a token is passed back to the app which can be used for calls which require authentication.

Is there a way to do this differently like how firebase does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Resource Owner Password Credentials grant is technically supported in AAD.

See [OAuth 2 Resource Owner Password Credentials grant in AzureAd](https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-grant-in-AzureAd)

However, this flow, for a number of reasons, is not recommended to be used. Take a look at what they say in the [OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3):

> The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in cases where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the client, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged application. **The authorization server should take special care when enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not viable.**

If you try to do this with AAD, you will run into issues with consent, multi-factor authentication, multi-tenant scenarios, and more. Furthermore, think in the perspective of the customer. One of the big reasons end users like using a trusted identity provider is because they are *trusted*.

As a customer, I would feel uncomfortable typing my Azure Active Directory password into a form on another website. Instead, I would want to type my password ONLY into the trusted IDP controlled website, and know that OAuth 2.0 can ensure that my sign in is verified without leaking any sensitive information to the website I am signing into.

Comment: yeah everything I read online seemed to warn against doing this, I'm mostly worried because the azure ux experience is odd at times (for example when registring an account you have to click 'send code' for the email seperate to clicking 'submit' on the registration form which is different to literally every other sign up flow on the planet).

Comment: Sorry for your poor experience there. Note that there is a forum to give feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory), but I will also try to send your feedback internally.